# Stop httpd, apache2

Tags: macos, apache2, apache

When I stop httpd and apache2 localhost still shows "It works!". Why ? I want reinstall apache2, how to completely remove it ? (I done it port uninstall php5 and apache2)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you just should press cmd+f5 to flush cache of your browser?

Answer (score -1):

Try this `cd /usr/local/apache2/bin` (your apache install fodler)then when you enter apache bin folder run `./apachectl stop`
Then run this `sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common`
It all depends how the apache was installed, it is possible that httpd was not added to services so the stop command wont be recognized for it.

Comment: Have you see tag "osx" ? btw. apt-get is global app